# Google Search in Python script

Tags: python, ajax, api, google-custom-search, bing-search

I want to write a python script in which I enter a question and as an answer I get reply from google custom search api or Bing or any other search api (any one). I tried using google custom search API but it gave me this script:

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = 'someurl';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'someurl' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Since I am not using any html page and just require answer in python console how do I do this? Is there somethere method to do so other than API call?

Answer (score 0):

To do google searches there are many modules like [google](https://github.com/MarioVilas/google) or [Google-Search-API](https://github.com/abenassi/Google-Search-API). But if you want to do many searches and have many requests google will block you and you'll get error 503. Before there was option to use other APIs but like Bing and Yahoo, but neither of them are free anymore. Only free API that does internet searches is [FAROO API](http://www.faroo.com/hp/api/api.html). But there is still one option to do google search by using [selenium webdriver](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). Selenium is used to imitate browser usage and it has [options](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#drivers) to use Firefox, Chrome, Edge or Safari webdrivers (it actually opens Chrome and does your search), but this is annoying because you don't actually want to see the browser. But there is solution for this you can use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). Download from [here](http://phantomjs.org/download.html). Extracted and see how to use it in the example below (I wrote a simple class which you can use, you just need to change the path to PhantomJS):

```
import time
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
from selenium import webdriver


class Browser:

    def __init__(self, path, initiate=True, implicit_wait_time = 10, explicit_wait_time = 2):
        self.path = path
        self.implicit_wait_time = implicit_wait_time    # http://www.aptuz.com/blog/selenium-implicit-vs-explicit-waits/
        self.explicit_wait_time = explicit_wait_time    # http://www.aptuz.com/blog/selenium-implicit-vs-explicit-waits/
        if initiate:
            self.start()
        return

    def start(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(path)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(self.implicit_wait_time)
        return

    def end(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        return

    def go_to_url(self, url, wait_time = None):
        if wait_time is None:
            wait_time = self.explicit_wait_time
        self.driver.get(url)
        print('[*] Fetching results from: {}'.format(url))
        time.sleep(wait_time)
        return

    def get_search_url(self, query, page_num=0, per_page=10, lang='en'):
        query = quote_plus(query)
        url = 'https://www.google.hr/search?q={}&num={}&start={}&nl={}'.format(query, per_page, page_num*per_page, lang)
        return url

    def scrape(self):
        #xpath migth change in future
        links = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h3[@class='r']/a[@href]") # searches for all links insede h3 tags with class "r"
        results = []
        for link in links:
            d = {'url': link.get_attribute('href'),
                 'title': link.text}
            results.append(d)
        return results

    def search(self, query, page_num=0, per_page=10, lang='en', wait_time = None):
        if wait_time is None:
            wait_time = self.explicit_wait_time
        url = self.get_search_url(query, page_num, per_page, lang)
        self.go_to_url(url, wait_time)
        results = self.scrape()
        return results




path = '<YOUR PATH TO PHANTOMJS>/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe' ## SET YOU PATH TO phantomjs
br = Browser(path)
results = br.search('Python')
for r in results:
    print(r)

br.end()
```